# Efficient way to use fork join pool with multiple parallel streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am using three streams which needs to call http requests. All of the calls are independent. So, I use parallel streams and collect the results from http response.

Currently I am using three separate parallel streams for these operations.

```
Map<String, ClassA> list1 = listOfClassX.stream().parallel()
        .map(item -> {
            ClassA instanceA = httpGetCall(item.id);
            return instanceA;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(item -> item.id, item -> item);

Map<String, ClassB> list1 = listOfClassY.stream().parallel()
        .map(item -> {
            ClassB instanceB = httpGetCall(item.id);
            return instanceB;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(item -> item.id, item -> item);

Map<String, ClassC> list1 = listOfClassZ.stream().parallel()
        .map(item -> {
            ClassC instanceC = httpGetCall(item.id);
            return instanceC;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(item -> item.id, item -> item);
```

It runs the three parallel streams separately one after another though each call is independent.

Will common fork join pool help in this case to optimize the use of thread pool here?

Is there any other way to optimize the performance of this code further?

Comment: I think you can use `CompletableFuture.allOf()` in this case. especially each call is independent. this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52370888/completablefuture-allof-join-vs-completablefuture-join/52426642) will help you.

Comment: Streams are optimized for CPU bound tasks, so even a single parallel stream might be unsuited for your I/O bound tasks. Use an `ExecutorService` configured to the desired level of concurrency. You may combine it with `CompletableFuture`, if feasible.