# Has CompletableFuture.allOf() any advantage over a loop with CompletableFuture.join() when just waiting for completion?

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency, completable-future

I am making multiple async calls to my database. I store all those async calls on a `List<CompletableFuture<X>> list`. I want to collect all the results together, so I need to wait for all of those calls to complete.

One way is to create a `CompletableFuture.allOf(list.toArray(...))...`

Another way is to use: `list.stream.map(cf -> cf.join())...`

I was just wondering if there are any advantages of creating the global CompletableFuture and waiting for it to complete (when all the individual CompletableFuture  complete) over directly waiting for the individual CompletableFutures to complete.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52426642/8746228) help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `main` thread gets blocked either way.

```java
static CompletableFuture<Void> getFailingCF() {
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("getFailingCF :: Started getFailingCF.. ");
        throw new RuntimeException("getFailingCF:: Failed");
    });
}

static CompletableFuture<Void> getOkCF() {
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("getOkCF :: Started getOkCF.. ");
        LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(3));
        System.out.println("getOkCF :: Completed getOkCF.. ");
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
     List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
     futures.add(getFailingCF());
     futures.add(getOkCF());
      
     // using CompletableFuture.allOf
     var allOfCF = CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));
     
     allOfCF.join();
    
     // invoking join on individual CF
     futures.stream()
            .map(CompletableFuture::join)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
 }
```

In the code snippet above, the difference lies in handling exception: The `CompletableFuture.allOf(..)` wraps any exception thrown by any of the `CompletableFuture`s while allowing rest of the threads (executing the `CompletableFuture`) continue their execution.

The `list.stream.map(cf -> cf.join())...` way immediately throws the exception and terminates the app (and all threads executing the CFs in the list).

Note that invoking `join()` on `allOf` throws the wrapped exception, too. It will also terminate the app. But, by this time, unlike `list.stream.map(cf -> cf.join())...`, the rest of the threads have completed their processing.

---

`allOfCF.whenComplete(..)`  is one of the graceful ways to handle the execution result (normal or exceptional) of all the CFs:

```java
 allOfCF.whenComplete((v, ex) -> {
     System.out.println("In whenComplete...");
     System.out.println("----------- Exception Status ------------");

     System.out.println(" 1: " + futures.get(0).isCompletedExceptionally());
     System.out.println(" 2: " + futures.get(1).isCompletedExceptionally());
 });
```

In the `list.stream.map(cf -> cf.join())...` way, one needs to wrap the `join()` call in `try/catch`.

Comment: 1+, my answer was indeed idiotic, though I ultimately wanted to express the same thing.